# Installing and Running Python 3 in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, terminal, installation

I have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZmkImpGSAU) tutorial. I've used brew to install python 3 but when I try to run a simple command in the terminal:

```
print('hello')
```

I get the following error message:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'hello''
```

And when I type the command:

```
python -V
```

It says that my version is 2.7.10. Any idea as to why I can't run python in the terminal / version 3 isn't showing up?

[image]

(The red lines on the right are crossing out myfullname$)

Comment: You cannot write Python code directly in the command line. The terminal is expecting bash.

Comment: Even after typing python + enter, I type python -V and receive "NameError: name 'python' is not defined". Same thing when typing python3 + enter. The print command is working though.

Comment: The key was to quit (), then type python3 + enter, just fyi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't start python. You were still using the bash shell.
Type `python` and press enter. Then you'll be using python